# How to remove Blazor app loading time on browser

Tags: load, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I’m just creating a demo Blazor web assembly application and realized that refreshing the app in the browser will show the ‘Loading…’ text from the index.html page. Even if this text is removed, the app reloads shows a white screen on the browser (which means it is taking some milliseconds to load the app components). Is there any way, that I can remove this take gap totally and load the app components quickly on the browser page? Or does it have anything to do with app memory?

Because when I host this app through an IIS server and run it on a browser, the app refresh is taking even more time to reload.

[PS: I'm not looking for any custom loading screens, rather avoid this completely.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtehx.png)

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What recommendations in there did you try?

Comment: Yes, my application has components like a Header, footer, carousel, and additional info displaying components (total 4). Also, there are JS interop calls from the Header component to load particular styles and other click and mouse hover functions in the component itself.
 I minimized most of these calls and hover functions. Also reduced the data transfer  through parameters between the components.

Comment: After building in release and publishing, it should not take that long. Also, enable caching on the browser, otherwise, the assembly is going to be downloaded every time.

Comment: If there was a way to speed this up, don't you think it would have been implemented already?

Comment: One solution I have seen proposed:  use a standard MVC page as your landing page.  Then use Blazor pages for other pages on your site.  The rationale being: you want your landing page to load as quick as possible so as not to lose users interest.  If other pages on your site load a bit slower it might be acceptable.

Comment: @JasonD thanks for the idea, it's a good backup if nothing works without delay.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is prerendering:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly

This allows components to be rendered as static HTML, served to the browser upon first load (no loading... screen), then "hyrdrates" the components to enable functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The initial loading comes from the app transfer of the .NET runtime to the browser, as you can see in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0

What you could do is follow some of the suggestions detailed in the "Minimize app download size" section. The two things I'd look at mostly are the IL Trimming that you can configure to reduce a bit of what the framework transfers, and also Lazy Loading so that only the bare minimum is loaded when you start the application.

Comment: I did IL trimming before publishing my project release edition to the server and removed all the unused assembly files. Still, I see the loading delay. 

And is there any lazy loading technique to load the home page image (first image in a carousel)? Because the image loading is taking around 190-230ms in local and more than 780ms from the deployment server.